# Tensorflow boxes not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have been following this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) in order to set up tensorflow in a python environment.
In the end, the program is supposed to return several pictures with boxes around the dogs (see the end of the page). I have followed the instructions exactly and have not found any problems during the installation. However, in the end, I get the pictures but no boxes or identifiers:
[my result (no boxes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5K0G.jpg)
How could I solve this problem?
Edit: I am on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found that the model was the problem.
Try to change your model into this or any other model:

```
# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
```